# Showing small popup when I assigned shortcut key to menu

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have added one menu item and assigned shortcut key Ctr+F for `FindDialog` in the Eclipse RCP application. But after running and press `Ctrl+F` it comes a small popup right corner bottom of the application which shows Find and `Find And Replace` option. Then when I click Find option only its showing Find Dialog. Why does it so? How to show the `FindDialog` without having the small popup? Please find the screen shot.

[image]

Comment: You have two shortcuts assigned to Ctrl+F.

Answer (score 0):

It means **Find** command and **Find and Replace** command have the same shortcut. You can check org.eclipse.ui.bindings in Extension tab of product for duplicates. As alternative you can use text from your question *Press "Ctrl+Shift+L" to open the preference page* - it will open Keys preference page.

Comment: is there any way to show only one shortcut? In eclipse IDE I can see only one, where In my application why I see two shortcuts? Is there any way to change that behaviour?

Comment: You can change this behavior. If you need only your shortcuts then specify it in application. If you need both - change one of them. If you want to see 2 shortcuts try press Ctrl+Shift+L when this small panel is displayed.